# How to extract and remove few range of indices from a two dimensional numpy array in python

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I am struck into a problem and it is required to be resolved. I have created a two dimensional matrix from a continuous range of length. Now, I want to extract few ranges of indices from that 2D matrix. Suppose, I have a matrix like:

a = [[ 12 4 35 0 26 15 100]
[17 37 29 87 46 95 120]]

Now I want to delete some part based on the indices for example: index number 2 to 5 and 8:10. After deleting I want to return my array with same two dimension. Thank you in advance.

I have tried many ways like numpy stacking and concatenating but I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: you can use:  `numpy.delete` to achieve this.

Comment: The question in its current format is unanswerable because the inner lists of `a` are of different lengths `6` and `7` respectively.

Comment: The assignment to `a` is invalid in Python. There is no comma between the two inner lists. The lists are also of unequal length, which is deprecated in a numpy array. In any case, once you've deleted some items if it wasn't of unequal length it will likely be when you are done.

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: @D.L, Could you please tell how to use np.delete for more than one indices range?

Answer (score 0):

deleting columns of the `numpy array` is relatively straight forward.

using a corrected example from the question, it looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [12, 4, 35, 0, 26, 15, 100], 
    [17, 37, 29, 87, 46, 95, 120]])
print('first array:')
print(a)

# deletes items from first row
b = np.delete(a, [2,3], 1)
print('second array:')
print(b)
```

which gives this:

```
first array:
[[ 12   4  35   0  26  15 100]
 [ 17  37  29  87  46  95 120]]
second array:
[[ 12   4  26  15 100]
 [ 17  37  46  95 120]]
```

So the columns 2,3,4 have been removed in the above example.